# Apply a function that manipulates a dataframe to a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has an index and a couple of other columns. The value in the index are not unique (in fact they repeat many times. Each index can be repeated ~10-20 times). Basically imagine something like this:

```
import random
random.seed(4)
arr = [[random.randint(1, 4)] + [random.random() for _ in xrange(3)] for i in xrange(5)]
df_ = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']).set_index('id')
```

[image]

Now I need to calculate some values based on id. These values are:

- percentage of 0 in the some particular column
- percentage of values that fall into some ranges
- something similar to the previous questions

Let's for simplicity assume that I need only values in the range `[-inf, 0.25], [0.25, 0.75], [0.75, inf]` and I will use only `col1`

What I currently have done is:

Created a function that takes a dataframe and returns these 3 numbers.

```
def f(df):
    v1 = len(df[df['col1'] <= 0.25])
    v2 = len(df[(df['col1'] >= 0.25) & (df['col1'] <= 0.75)])
    v3 = len(df[df['col1'] >= 0.75])
    return v1, v2, v3
```

Now I am iterating all values in the index, extract data related to this index and applying this function to it. This way I create the new dataframe with the statistics I need.

```
data = []
for id in set(df_.index.values):
    v1, v2, v3 = f(df_.loc[id])
    data.append((id, v1, v2, v3))

res_ = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'less_25', '25_75', 'more_75'])
```

---

Now everything works (I believe correctly), but it is incredibly slow. I need to calculate this data on approximately 1M rows df, where there are ~50k unique ids. My approach will most probably take a day.

I believe that with a smart [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) or may be something else this can be achieved way faster.

Comment: How about the following for the first two questions: `df_.groupby(df_.index).agg({'col1':lambda x: np.size(x[x==0])})` and `df_.groupby(df_.index).agg({'col1':lambda x: np.size(x[(x>0.2) & (x<0.5)])})` Obviously adjust to your column names and values. Oh yes, `import numpy as np` as well.

Comment: @Torrinos thank you. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: You should just `.sum()` the boolean `Series` directly, rather than take the size of a boolean slice. It will shave a good chunk of overall time off.

Comment: I.e use something like `lambda S: ((S>0.2) & (S<0.5)).sum()`

Comment: I believe he asked for a percentage, so you need to count occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by using `pd.cut` across the entire `df_` to start.

```
cat = pd.cut(df_.values.flatten(), [-np.inf, .25, .75, np.inf])
cat_arr = cat.get_values().reshape(df_.shape)
cat_df = pd.DataFrame(cat_arr, df_.index, df_.columns)
```

***Take a look***

```
pd.concat([df_, cat_df], axis=1, keys=['df_', 'cat'])
```

[image]

***Get Counts of `cat` per `id`***

```
cat_count = cat_df.stack().groupby(level=[0, 1]) \
                  .value_counts() \
                  .unstack().fillna(0)
cat_count
```

[image]

***Get frequency of `cat` per `id`***

```
cat_count = cat_df.stack().groupby(level=[0, 1])\
                  .value_counts(normalize=True) \
                  .unstack().fillna(0)
cat_count
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, do not have time to review it now. Will do this tomorrow. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Reposting my comment as answer. It uses group by index with a custom agglomeration function based on numpy.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(4)
arr = [[random.randint(1, 4)] + [random.random() for _ in xrange(3)]\
    for i in xrange(10)]
df_ = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['id', 'col1', 'col2','col3']).set_index('id')

# Percentage of zeros in col1
res1 = df_.groupby(df_.index).agg({'col1':lambda x: np.size(x[x==0])/np.size(x)})
# Percentage of values in given range in col1
res2 = df_.groupby(df_.index).agg({'col1':lambda x:\
     np.size(x[(x>0.2) & (x<0.5)])/np.size(x)})
```

Output:

```
In [22]: res1
Out[22]: 
    col1
id      
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    0.0

In [23]: res2
Out[23]: 
        col1
id          
1   0.333333
2   0.000000
3   0.000000
4   0.200000
```